# Pass variable based on bundle name to webpack source at compile time

Tags: node.js, webpack, dynamic-import, webpack-plugin

I have a scenario where multiple bundle have the same entry point, called `index.js`

I then inside that file have dynamic import for the respective sub modules by looking on a `env` variable:

```
await import("api/" + process.env.API")
```

The problem with this is that webpack will bundle all files under `api/` since it can't know what that dynamic value is at compile time.

The value of `process.env.API` is actually the same as the name of the bundle. So I've tried to do use the magic comments feature of webpack to get it working:

```
await import(
/* webpackInclude: [name] */
"api/" + process.env.API")
```

But according to the documentation,  placeholders are only used for chunk names and not for include/exclude feature.

I've also tried using the context replacement plug-in with callback but the context callback contains no information about the bundle name.

Is it possible to somehow define a plug-in or configure a value which would be resolved as the bundle name at compile time?

Comment: is this an for example react.js app or node.js, or something else?

Comment: The example is node.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the dynamicImport syntax you usually are generating individual chunks. And as far as I understand your question you want to name these chunks depending on the dynamic path variable?

A way to do that is
      `import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ 'api/${process.env.API')`

**EDIT**

Dynamic chunk names seem to be generated at runtime (at least thats how I explained it to myself), which is why environment variables might not be available. Save your .env variable in a JS variable and load your dynamic import like this:

```
const api = process.env.API;
const module = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ 'api/${api}');
```

This will output correctly names chunks containing only the module corresponding to the path.

**EDIT 2 (from OP)**

I also had a problem with babel when using the wrong plugin which caused webpack to transpile `import` statments to `require`. Solved using:
`@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`

Comment: Not exactly. The problem I have is that all resources under `api` is bundled for all entry points. There is a one to one relationship between entry points and corresponding `/api/{name}` resource. So this will create unnecessary code which will never run for all the bundles

Comment: @Richard I have just tried it myself and updated my answer